# Calculate the power of 2, java

Tags: java, recursion

I want to calculate the power of 2 using recursion. Here is my code:

```
class Aufg1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int erg = zweiHochPositiv(10);
    }

    public static int zweiHochPositiv(int exponent){
        if(exponent > 0)
            return (2*zweiHochPositiv(exponent--));
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

I get a lot of errors at

```
return (2*zweiHochPositiv(exponent--));
```

but I have no idea what may be wrong.

Comment: Post decrementation is a bad idea here - you're going to have infinite recursion.

Comment: For reference, `1 << exponent` will be faster and clearer in just about every case.

Comment: @cHao: Unless the compiler/runtime properly optimize multiplication by two.

Comment: 1) **Read** the error messages. 2) **Show** them.

Comment: @cdhowie: Even then.  You'd have to optimize the multiplication *and* get rid of the recursive function call.

Comment: @cHao: You mean like I addressed in my answer? :P

Comment: @cdhowie: Not really.  You addressed the error, but calculating 2^N still requires N function calls.  Contrast with `1 << N`, which requires *none*.

Comment: @cHao: Ah, I see what you mean -- replacing the recursion with one instruction.  However, the OP states *"I want to calculate the power of 2 using recursion"* which makes me think this is homework or some other kind of exercise.  Therefore it would probably be more helpful to explain how to fix the existing code than explain how the approach is wrong.  (Which it's not -- slow, maybe, but not inherently incorrect.)

Comment: @cdhowie: Agreed.  It's not inherently incorrect.  I just thought i'd mention there's a better way, that's built into the language, in case that's not known.  Most people trying to calculate powers of two shouldn't be doing it recursively.  :)

Comment: @cHou: Understood.  Bit shift would definitely be the preferred way to do this.

Comment: Even if the method is inlined, the branch will be more expensive than a shift. So 1 << N will always be faster.

Comment: @Peter: And recursive calls cannot be inlined.  (Though the tailcall recursion could be optimized to produce a similar result.)

Comment: @cdhowie, good point, AFAIK, Java doesn't do tail-call optimisations.

Comment: @Peter:  It'd be faster on x86, but i couldn't rule out the possibility of some platform where bit shifts cost more than branches.  Yeah, it'd be a broken design, but it's possible.  Unless we know the CPU, we can't guarantee anything -- we can only make some reasonable generalizations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
return (2*zweiHochPositiv(exponent--));
```

with

```
return (2*zweiHochPositiv(exponent - 1));
```

`exponent--` evaluates to the value of the `exponent` variable and *then* decrements it.  So when you call `zweiHochPositiv(1)`, the method will call `zweiHochPositiv(1)` again.

As a result, this method, when called with a value > 0, will recurse indefinitely and ultimately overflow the stack.

Comment: @barti_ddu: You would be wrong to prefer predecrement -- the variable `exponent` is never used again, and so you have just subtracted one and stored the value in a variable that will never be used again.  In other words, `exponent - 1` does not perform any unnecessary memory writes, while `--exponent` does.  This may appear to be a micro-optimization, but it is in fact a style issue.  Why would you be modifying a variable you never intend to use again?

Comment: +1. no need to change the value of `exponent`, which should be made final, too.

Comment: for this case compiler (at least sun java compiler) will generate identical bytecode; however, it is good You've pointed this out

Comment: hmm, just copy-pasted OP example and re-checked compiler output.. yes, pre-decrement usage results in one extra operation in the bytecode (this was a surprise to me); thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use prefix version of `--`.

This should work:

```
return (2*zweiHochPositiv(--exponent));
```

Explanation: `exponent--` will never actually lower `exponent`'s value, so you're calling your recursive function every time with the same value, and that will blow your stack.

`--exponent` will lower it's value by one, so you should get desired behaviour.

Comment: You still doesn't describe what prefixing the integer with `--` actually does ;)

Comment: I think this solution is a bit confusing: I would expect that the `exponent` is being used later in the method since it's being decremented. (despite changing an argument...)

Answer (score 1):

I think an efficient way of doing it would be to use the binary representation property of a "power of 2" - its just a bit shift of 1, "exponent" number of times.

Hence, 2^2 = 1 << 2 = (in binary) ....0000 0100 = 4

Answer (score 0):

return (2*zweiHochPositiv(--exponent));